# How can I take log of particular columns?

Tags: r

I have this data

```
structure(list(DATE = 19620101:19620106, PRECIP = c(10.54, 6.39, 
0.01, 0, 0.02, 20.94), OBS_Q = c(2.39, 2.38, 2.22, 2.24, 2.26, 
5.13), swb = c(4.11, 3.92, 3.8, 3.8, 3.77, 7.16), gr4j = c(3.7, 
4.24, 3.73, 3.24, 2.98, 4.93), isba = c(4.82, 3.44, 4.18, 3.01, 
2.88, 6.35), noah = c(3.11, 2.84, 2.57, 2.59, 2.84, 4.83), sac = c(2.83, 
2.84, 2.73, 2.87, 2.94, 6), swap = c(2.16, 2.56, 2.08, 2.19, 
3.65, 4.43), vic.mm.day. = c(3.44, 3.14, 3.37, 3.15, 2.88, 4.52
)), .Names = c("DATE", "PRECIP", "OBS_Q", "swb", "gr4j", "isba", 
"noah", "sac", "swap", "vic.mm.day."), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

And a function that does three things

- Subsets based on what 'model' is mentioned(one of the column names of df)
- Outputs dfcal with 3 columns
- Outputs dfcallog with the log of those values

The function

```
dataprep.allcal<-function(df,model){
      dfcal<<-subset(df, select=c("DATE",model, "OBS_Q"))
      dfcallog<-subset(df, select=c("DATE",model, "OBS_Q"))
      cols<-colnames(dfcallog)
      dfcallog[cols] <<- log(dfcallog[cols])
    }


dataprep.allcal(df=df,model='sac')
```

The problem with this, it converts the date to log as well.

Can you tell me how I can apply the log only on model and OBS_Q column?

Comment: Why are you using `<<-` if you want to retrieve `dfcallog`, just add it at the end. Also, why are you doing `subset(df, select=c("DATE",model, "OBS_Q"))` twice? Finally, if you don't want to update the `Date` column, just don't select it? Something like `dfcallog[c(model, "OBS_Q")] <- log(dfcallog[c(model, "OBS_Q")])`?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by end? I used << to put the variables in global environment...Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to do it by excluding `DATE` from the `cols` variable:

```
dataprep.allcal<-function(df,model){
  dfcal<<-subset(df, select=c("DATE",model, "OBS_Q"))
  #need to use the <<- operator below
  dfcallog<<-subset(df, select=c("DATE",model, "OBS_Q"))
  cols<-colnames(dfcallog)
  cols<-cols[!cols %in% 'DATE']
  dfcallog[cols] <<- log(dfcallog[cols])
}

dataprep.allcal(df=df,model='sac')
```

Output:

```
> dfcal
      DATE  sac OBS_Q
1 19620101 2.83  2.39
2 19620102 2.84  2.38
3 19620103 2.73  2.22
4 19620104 2.87  2.24
5 19620105 2.94  2.26
6 19620106 6.00  5.13

> dfcallog
      DATE      sac     OBS_Q
1 19620101 1.040277 0.8712934
2 19620102 1.043804 0.8671005
3 19620103 1.004302 0.7975072
4 19620104 1.054312 0.8064759
5 19620105 1.078410 0.8153648
6 19620106 1.791759 1.6351057
```

Note:

I don't know if this is a typo but you should have `dfcallog<-subset(df, select=c("DATE",model, "OBS_Q"))` with a `<<-` operator because using a `<-` operator at the beginning and then a `<<-` operator at the last command in the function will produce an error because `<<-` looks at the `parent.environment` to find a variable and thus you would get an `object not found` error.